# Prove that if $a_{1}\geq a_{2},a_{2}\geq a_{3},\dots,a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$ then $a_{1}\geq a_{n}$, with $a_{1}=a_{n}$ iff all the $a$'s are equal.

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Prove that if $a_{1}\geq a_{2},a_{2}\geq a_{3},\dots,a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$ then $a_{1}\geq a_{n}$, with $a_{1}=a_{n}$ if and only if all the $a$'s are equal.

---

Proof:

Suppose $a_{1}\geq a_{2},a_{2},\geq a_{3},\dots,a_{n-1}\geq a_{n}$, then by the algebraic definition of inequalities, we have each of $a_{1}-a_{2},a_{2}-a_{3},\dots,a_{n-1}-a_{n}$ either in the set of all positive numbers $P$ or in the set $O$ containing $0$. So the sum $(a_{1}-a_{2})+(a_{2}-a_{3})+\dots+(a_{n-1}-a_{n})=a_{1}-a_{n}$ is either in $P$ or $O$.

In the case $a_{1}-a_{n}$ is in $O$, $a_{1}=a_{n}$ since $(a_{1}-a_{2})+(a_{2}-a_{3})+\dots+(a_{n-1}-a_{n})=a_{1}-a_{n}=0\Longleftrightarrow a_{1}=a_{2}=\dots=a_{n}.$

In the case $a_{1}-a_{n}$ is in $P$, $a_{1}>a_{n}$.

Thus, $a_{1}\geq a_{n}.$

---

Proof check, and comments, and also any other ways to show this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change I would make is your 3rd line from the bottom. I would explicitly say that the reason $a_1 - a_n = 0 \iff a_1 = a_2 = ... = a_n$ is because of the construction of $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n$. That is, the only reason your middle terms cancel out is because the sum telescopes—not necessarily because $a_1 = a_2$. (This is a bit nit-picky, though; the construction of these is such regardless of whether or not you remind the reader of it).

You could also do this proof with a contradiction and some induction (because I'll use any excuse to invoke induction):

Let $S = \{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n\}$ such that $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq ... \geq a_n$. Assume $a_m \geq a_n$ for all $m \leq n$. By the construction of $S$, $a_m \geq a_n \geq a_{n+1}$. Therefore, for all $m \leq n$, $a_m \geq a_n$. Thus, if $a_1 < a_n$, we would come to a contradiction, since $1 \leq n$. So, $a_1$ is necessarily greater than or equal to $a_n$.

Similarly, $a_1 = a_n$ necessarily means $a_m = a_1 = a_n$ for all $1 \leq m \leq n$.

It's kind of an unecessary stretch...

... but I love induction.

Answer (score 1):

If for all $m\leq n$ you have $a_m\leq a_{m-1}$, then $a_n\leq a_1$. Moreover, if $a_n=a_1$, then for all $m\leq n$
$$a_1=a_n\leq a_m\leq a_1,$$
and thus $a_m=a_1$ for all $m$.